# Google Cloud Functions - Python - HTTP Trigger URL Without Function Name

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud Function triggered via HTTP.

The trigger URL is in the format:

https://europe-west1-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION-NAME

This works fine, however I need to beable to access it at:

https://europe-west1-PROJECT-NAME.cloudfunctions.net/

Is there a way of doing this? I have not been able to find a definitive answer for this via their documentation or Google Search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You must use the URL that was assigned to your function at the time of deployment.  You can't rewrite the URL on the hostname/domain that's given to your project.

You can, however, [use Firebase Hosting to proxy URLs to Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#connect_functions_to_hosting) in the same project.  You will need to use the domain given to you by Firebase Hosting, or bring your own domain.